# Ruby toplevel == JS global object?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Coming to Ruby from JS, I think it'd be easy to learn if I compare and contrast between those two. When I stumbled into Ruby [toplevel](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/) I can't help but think of it as similar to the global object (window object) in JavaScript.

Am I correct in making this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not similar in any meaningful way except that both objects act as `this`/`self` outside the context of any other object. In any other respect, they are quite different. There is no generally useful way to refer to `main` outside of the top level like there is with `window`. Global variables are true global variables, and constants or methods defined in the context of `main` are not actually defined on `main`, but on the Object class.

Comment: you can refer to the `binging` of top-level in ruby by accessing the `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` constant.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, you are wrong.

Ruby top level is simply a Object. Every top level hierarchy ends in Object. Other words every thing is considered  as a object.

You are confusing the top level objects with the objects that are shared across all instances.

in Javascript, the window object is a top one and can be shared (yo can call it a static) across multiple calls across the same page. thats why we called it as global object.

its correct to say, In both Javascript and Ruby top level is a object (Window is still a object in javascript).